# safari web app open rel="external" in safari instead of web-app

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, iphone-web-app

I'm trying to make my site a web app. The first time i watched it all the links opend in the safari browser. after adding a script to the site that whas no longer a problem.
This is the script:

```
if(("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone){
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        if ($(this).attr('target') !== '_blank') {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
}
```

only all links with 'rel="external"' stay in the web app. also if i set them to target"_blank".

i thought: what if i have a script that looks for the rel="external file". editing the above script doesn't work.

so what i want is a script that tests on the rel=external element. if it finds it the link stays untoucht and if it doesn't find the rel=external in the link it does someting like:

```
e.preventDefault();
window.location = $(this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
if(! $(this).is('[rel="external"]') ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
} else {
    window.open( $(this).attr('href') ); //opens a new window
}
```

EDITED: added an else condition that would cause linkes with rel="external" to open in a new window.

Comment: this one seems okey. still it ain't doing what i want. all links stay in the web app. also the ones with rel="external". witch i want to open outside the web app in the regulair iOs safari

Comment: You want them to stay in the web app and open in regular Safari at the same time? That is what it appears you're saying. This code answers your original question.

Comment: that is not what i want. if i have a link like <a href="stuff.html">link</a> than i want it to stay in web app. and if the link is someting like <a href="stuff.html" rel="external">link</a> i want it to open in the normal browser.

Comment: So, the opposite of this?

Comment: indeed. the opposite. this script is realy awesome.. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

To open an external browser window when in web app (Standalone)
You need to use _system in the window.open function.
Also on iPhone Safari has a bug that does not repaint the parent window correctly when closing the newly opened window.

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0});
window.open(encodeURI(url),"_system",windowOpenSettings);
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: top});
return;
```

All the scrolling is just to repaint IOS window and to place the user back in the same position as before the click.